# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `jobs`)

Tags: php, laravel

Error Picture:

[image]

These are all my errors that I get but I have 63 frames erros I'm not going to list. Since going through all would be to much I guess.

A fix would be good.

My files  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnPb5n9nCL2ipyH_Wu61GVkT-X-k?e=TGpkoM
///

```
  // run the SQL against the PDO connection. Then we can calculate the time it
    // took to execute and log the query SQL, bindings and time in our memory.
    try {
        $result = $callback($query, $bindings);
    }

    // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new QueryException(
            $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
        );
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Log a query in the connection's query log.
 *
 * @param  string  $query
 * @param  array  $bindings
```

///

Comment: I'm not going to wade through all the files and folders in your OneDrive to recreate this.

Comment: Please share more details such that others can help you - but also, please focus on the **minimal** steps needed to trigger your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try running `php artisan migrate`.
If that fails, check your database credentials in `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your database first, did that table exist? it seems like your table (jobs) isn't created from your database. try to create a new migration file since laravel support create a new table from a file.

```
php artisan make:migration (your migration name)
```

Then go to that file to edit your table schema
[Laravel Migration Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations)

If you created that database on local machine and it works, try to export your local database to public database.

Or last option, check your Model File. in Laravel 8+, All models File goes to  **App\Model** Directory. So it must be :

> use App\Models\Job;

Answer (score 0):

check to see if your mysql.sock file isn't found.

You can restart the MySQL server and see, whether this fixes it or you add/edit this line to your php.ini:

```
     pdo_mysql.default_socket="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

Just check the path to the mysql.sock and adjust it accordingly - and you have to restart Apache after making changes to php.ini

or do the following:

```
    sudo mkdir /var/mysql
    cd /var/mysql
```

sudo ln -s /var/mysql/mysql.sock
i'm not really familiar with MACs so there might be little changes necessary to this

Answer (score -1):

Change DB_HOST value in your .env from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should this make a difference?